# Can I split a 120v outlet off a 240v air conditioner circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v

I have a 30amp 240v line running to my central  A/C unit. And I want to install an 20 amp 120v outlet next to it to run an air compressor unit. Is this possible and how is done?

Answer (score 4):

No. The National Electrical Code does not allow line to neutral loads on a 240 volt line.

Besides that the line to the air conditioner will not have a neutral for the 120 volt line anyway. If you cheat and use the equipment ground that is another very dangerous code violation.

Just run a new wire. It is not worth you and your family's safety to save a few dollars.

Good luck and stay safe!

Comment: Also,  you would just trip the breaker the moment the A/C cycles on.